# How to create a purchaseRequisition record in the standard mode?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Did anyone come across the  issue while adding line items in the new record created in the user event script
error:Cannot find function selectNewLine in object standard record

Comment: can you please post the code you have so far?

Comment: Please provide me with the code so that I can work out the issues

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.